# PostgreSQL Night Shift Timing Calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am doing a project where I need to calculate the shift timing using the RFID reader. This device will scan the RFID tags for each millisecond and keep it in buffer. I use a java programming to fetch those RFID details from the reader and updated in the POstgreSQL DB. I successfully updated the data which I fetched from the reader to postgresql database. I having problem in calculating the Night Shit.

Morning & Afternoon shift can be calculated successfully using the timestamp in the postgresql database because it comes within the date but night shift calculation was confising me because the shift was starting on first day and ends on the second day. e.g. night shift starts on 12-Jun-2016 and ends on 13-Jun-2016.

Here I don't know how to query the database.

Please help thanks in advance.

```
rfid_id | emp_id| User_name| access_time    
1076    | 13    | Username | 2016-07-12 21:08:26.796    
1077    | 13    | Username | 2016-07-12 21:08:27.139    
1078    | 13    | Username | 2016-07-12 21:08:27.342    
1079    | 13    | Username | 2016-07-12 21:08:27.358    
1080    | 13    | Username | 2016-07-12 21:08:27.389    
1081    | 13    | Username | 2016-07-12 21:08:27.436
```

This is the sample data.
For every second the RFID reader will scan the employee tags.

Comment: Your question doesn't say what you are trying to accomplish. You need to post some code examples that you have tried, e.g. one for the day shift calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest querying based on the start or end time of the the shift and the length of the shift. This will be consistent for any shift. For example, for an 8 hour shift starting on 28 July at 20:00 the query would be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  WHERE access_time BETWEEN to_timestamp('20160728 20:00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')
    AND to_timestamp('20160728 20:00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') + interval '8 hours'
```